# To Be Continued

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, crosswords

*Constructor's Note: This crossword was constructed to celebrate a work that will be continued.*

[image: Grid]

#### Clues

```
Across
1. Brood
4. Throb
8. Illustrate, as an illustration?
11. Purple shade
13. Serenaded
14. Blood ___
15. Line of defence?
16. Func. mapping 1 to 0 in maths
17. Unrefined
18. ___ four
19. "___ Land"
20. See 33-Across
22. Tree overexploited by early settlers in Australia
24. Apple device feature
25. Begins slowly
27. Fit in
31. "Sengoku ___" (Capcom franchise based on feudal Japan)
33. With 20-Across, alliterative mixed menu offering
35. Contract addendum
36. Prefix with phony
37. Contraction in poetry
39. Common first word
41. Be imminent
42. Its symbol looks like a rotated letter
44. Family name in superheroes
46. "Doki Doki Literature Club!" character
48. Girl, in Aussie slang
50. Catchphrase in "Wayne's World"
52. "Neon Genesis Evangelion" organisation
54. Manga and anime series meaning "Stray God"
57. Time period before "Friends" in an anime about an amnesiac adolescent
60. Be convenient for
61. In ___ (unborn)
63. Rock bottom
64. Genus for the flowering sugarbush
66. Betray, as a snitch
67. Flip over
68. Catch, as in a net
69. Famed fountain
70. Common email folder
71. Weapon for Wonder Woman
72. "Now it's clear to me"

Down
1. Hit, in a way
2. Floor worker, of a sort
3. First-class
4. Street display
5. Open, as a necklace
6. Some branded TVs
7. Measures
8. Type of ramp in sports
9. Part of Q.E.D.
10. Trick
12. Tolerates
13. Corporate pitcher, briefly
14. Haunted house worker, perhaps
21. Ad-___
23. James who voiced Flint's father in "Cloudy with a Chance of Meatballs"
26. Suffix with Einstein or Nobel
28. Hawaiian Disney girl
29. Something O3 has but not O2
30. Notable pill-taker of film
31. "Toccata and Fugue in D minor" composer
32. Hurt
34. Palmiers and pastizzis, e.g.
36. Layout language letters
38. Initials behind "The Pit and the Pendulum"
40. Autodesk modelling software
43. Favourable for everybody involved
45. Kidnapping demands
47. Greek ___
49. "Enter the Dragon" actor
51. Some Google Maps results
53. Ward off
55. ___ 2600
56. Doles (out)
57. Responsibility
58. Neck part
59. Tree of life location
62. Wander
65. Biological letters after messenger or transfer
```

#### Across TEXT (for use with [Across Lite](http://www.litsoft.com/across/alite/download/))

```
<ACROSS PUZZLE V2>
<TITLE>
To Be Continued
<AUTHOR>
Sp3000
<COPYRIGHT>
2018
<SIZE>
15x15
<GRID>
XXX...XXXX..XXX
XXXX.XXXXX.XXXX
XXXX.XXXXX.XXXX
XXXX.XXX.XXXXXX
.XXXXXXX.XXX...
...XXXXXX.XXXXX
.XXXXX.XXX.XXXX
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
XXXX.XXX.XXXXX.
XXXXX.XXXXXX...
...XXX.XXXXXXX.
XXXXXX.XXX.XXXX
XXXX.XXXXX.XXXX
XXXX.XXXXX.XXXX
XXX..XXXX...XXX
<ACROSS>
Brood
Throb
Illustrate, as an illustration?
Purple shade
Serenaded
Blood ___
Line of defence?
Func. mapping 1 to 0 in maths
Unrefined
___ four
"___ Land"
See 33-Across
Tree overexploited by early settlers in Australia
Apple device feature
Begins slowly
Fit in
"Sengoku ___" (Capcom franchise based on feudal Japan)
With 20-Across, alliterative mixed menu offering
Contract addendum
Prefix with phony
Contraction in poetry
Common first word
Be imminent
Its symbol looks like a rotated letter
Family name in superheroes
"Doki Doki Literature Club!" character
Girl, in Aussie slang
Catchphrase in "Wayne's World"
"Neon Genesis Evangelion" organisation
Manga and anime series meaning "Stray God"
Time period before "Friends" in an anime about an amnesiac adolescent
Be convenient for
In ___ (unborn)
Rock bottom
Genus for the flowering sugarbush
Betray, as a snitch
Flip over
Catch, as in a net
Famed fountain
Common email folder
Weapon for Wonder Woman
"Now it's clear to me"
<DOWN>
Hit, in a way
Floor worker, of a sort
First-class
Street display
Open, as a necklace
Some branded TVs
Measures
Type of ramp in sports
Part of Q.E.D.
Trick
Tolerates
Corporate pitcher, briefly
Haunted house worker, perhaps
Ad-___
James who voiced Flint's father in "Cloudy with a Chance of Meatballs"
Suffix with Einstein or Nobel
Hawaiian Disney girl
Something O3 has but not O2
Notable pill-taker of film
"Toccata and Fugue in D minor" composer
Hurt
Palmiers and pastizzis, e.g.
Layout language letters
Initials behind "The Pit and the Pendulum"
Autodesk modelling software
Favourable for everybody involved
Kidnapping demands
Greek ___
"Enter the Dragon" actor
Some Google Maps results
Ward off
___ 2600
Doles (out)
Responsibility
Neck part
Tree of life location
Wander
Biological letters after messenger or transfer
```

Comment: Great puzzle!  I'd strongly encourage you to add a [wrap-up](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5456/wrap-up-posts-what-should-the-formal-part-of-it-contain) post to the question.

Comment: I agree with @GentlePurpleRain $\diamondsuit$. DVL7 $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$ :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The trick to filling this crossword is to notice that

> as the title suggests, several of the words are missing their last letter. In fact, *all* of the Across words are!

The grid is filled like this:

> [image] 
>  The characters that get cut off (here, entered into the black square on the right) spell out WEBCOMIC STARRING AURORA, MARIAN, VIKTOR, AND HITOE. This is a reference to a comic with a fitting title: **[Endless Night](http://endless-night.net/)**.